# rename multiple csv filename with the information in the columns

Tags: r, csv, rename, filenames

There are many teachers filled their information in the csv columns, however, these csv files were labelled with a irregular name (e.g., 1.csv, apple school.csv, 003.csv, etc.).

These files contain the same columns (id, score, grade,class, school, city)

[image]

I'd like to rename the csv files in a regular way with what they filled in the columns in one go, such as "1A_S_L.csv"
then I can recognize this file is from the teacher of 1A, S school, L city

Many thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your input files in a folder named `in`, create an empty folder named `out`.
Then something like this will loop over the files in `in`, and copy them to files in `out` with names based on `grade`, `class`, `school` and `city`:

```
for (file_in in dir("in", full.names = TRUE)) {
  df <- read.csv(file_in)
  filename <- paste(df[1,"grade"], df[1,"class"], df[1,"school"], df[1,"city"], sep = "_")
  file_out <- paste0("out/", filename, ".csv")
  print(file_out)
  write.csv(df, file_out)
}
```